# How can I ensure the minimum width of a DIV?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
#sbr {
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and

```
<div id="sbr"></div>
```

The `<div>` is currently empty. I want to follow this `<div>` with another, so the minimum width of my first `<div>` must be 200px, however it seems not to work. Am I doing something wrong? Why does my first `<div>` seem to have no width?

Comment: It seems to work for me.  Try adding `border: 1px solid #000` to see it. http://jsfiddle.net/RT3pc/  There is no height to it though so that is why you just see a flat line.

Comment: you need to test your code via a developer tool like firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working actually, try to put min-height too and some background to see the changes:

```
#sbr {
    background:blue;
    float: left;
    min-height:200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

However, this won't work in IE (some versions), IE is having a problem in min-height or min-width. The min-height and min-width for IE is the height and width, but if you put width and height to your style, other browsers will fix your div to height and width specified. What you can do is  to use the underscore hack:

```
#sbr {
    background:blue;
    float: left;
    min-height:200px; /* This is min-height to other browser */
    min-width: 200px; /* This is min-width to other browser */
    _height:200px; /* This is min-height to IE, only to IE */
    _width:200px; /* This is min-width to IE, only to IE */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty div tags with requirements for min height/width, then perhaps you should use absolute positioning in CSS instead of keeping the div tags in the document flow.